# Graph API Query Using JavaScript API For Open Graph Actions And Objects

Tags: javascript, object, facebook-graph-api, action, facebook-javascript-sdk

when I use "me/nativeamericannews:be_proud_of/story?" in the Graph API Explorer, it correctly gives me a JSON response, but when I try to get that same response from my canvas app, it always provides an error. I have looked all over, but cannot see how I should be attempting to query for user interactions with my objects and actions. I am querying like this (be_proud_of is one of my actions and story is one of my objects):

```
function checkProudOf() {
    FB.api('/me/nativeamericannews:be_proud_of/story', 'post', function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occurred');
        } else {
            alert('Post for Info was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
}
```

I post the actions and everything works fine with:

```
function postProudOf() {
    FB.api('/me/nativeamericannews:be_proud_of' + '?story=' + encodeURI(document.URL), 'post', function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            // alert('Error occurred');
        } else {
            // alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
}
```

Any ideas? I want to be able to display aggregations and a user's history with my objects and actions when they visit my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well, that was embarrassing.  it was pretty simple, in the end. when i am reading the info from facebook, it is a "get" rather than a "post".

that fixed that issue.